# Is it possible to value bind a text field to an element in a specific index of an array?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a textarea like below. I want the text inside this text area to be available in an array but the following binding does not seem to work.

```
<textarea data-bind="value: myArray[0]"></textarea>
```

Is there a way to bind a value like this in kendo?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="view">
    <textarea data-bind="value: textareaValue[1]"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    textareaValue: ["aaa","bbb"]
});
kendo.bind($("#view"), viewModel);
</script>
```